# JQuery infinite loop - opacity reduces to almost 0

Tags: jquery, opacity, infinite-loop

I have a number of divs on a page which randomly and infinitely loops through backgrounds (in my example it is bg colour, but I will use bg images in final product) using JQuery fadein/out and random function.

My issue is that if the loop is left for approx 30 seconds you will see the background opacity reduces itself to almost 0 giving an empty space. It is worse in IE8, but also an issue in Chrome (still need to test in IE9 and Safari).

Can anyone explain WHY this is happening and (as importantly) how to fix it?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title> Background image loop</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(document).ready(function(){

    var InfiniteRotator =
    {
        init: function()
        {
            //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
            var initialFadeIn = 3000;

            //interval between items (in milliseconds)
            var itemInterval = 1000;

            //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
            var fadeTime = 2000;

            //count number of items
            var numberOfItems = $('.rotating-item').length;

            //set current item
            var currentItem = 1;

            //show first item
            $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);

            //loop through the items
            var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function(){
                $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);

            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*(numberOfItems-1)) + 1;
            currentItem = (currentItem+rand) % numberOfItems;

            $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);

            }, itemInterval);
        }
    };

    InfiniteRotator.init();

});
//]]>  

</script>


  <style type='text/css'>
    #rotating-item-wrapper {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 150px;
}  
li{
    float: left;
    width: 148px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 0 0 6px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
li div {  
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.rotating-item{            
    display: ;
    position: absolute;
    width: 148px;
    height: 150px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="rotating-item-wrapper">
    <li>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: red;"></div>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: green;"></div>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: yellow;"></div>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: purple;"></div>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: brown;"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: black;"></div>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: green;"></div>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: red;"></div>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: green;"></div>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: yellow;"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: red;"></div>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: green;"></div>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: yellow;"></div>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: purple;"></div>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: brown;"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: black;"></div>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: green;"></div>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: red;"></div>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: green;"></div>
        <div class="rotating-item" style="background-color: yellow;"></div>
    </li>
</ul>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your random number generation can produce the same number as before. Then your image fades out and *after that* it fades in again.

You have to fix the random number generation to not allow the last number again.

For timing issues and jQuery I always recommend using this new plugin jquery-timing. With that plugin your complete code (with fixed random choice) shrinks into:

```
$.fn.random = function(){
    return this.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*this.length));
}

$('.rotating-item').hide().first().fadeIn(initialFadeIn);
$('.rotating-item').repeat(itemInterval).fadeOut(fadeTime)
    .siblings().random().fadeIn(fadeTime).until($);
```

There is also a [similar example in the documentation](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/examples/random-banner-rotate.html) of the plugin.

Comment: Thanks @peter, however, no luck. The code seems to break on the last line - I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'repeat' " which I can't find any debugging for.
   
 $(document).ready(function(){    
    $.fn.random = function() {
    return this.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length));
    };

    $(function() {
       $('.rotating-item').hide().first().fadeIn(1000);
    $('.rotating-item').repeat(2000).fadeOut(1000)
        .siblings().random().fadeIn(2000).until($);
    });
});

If I remove "repeat" then I get the same error for "until"

Comment: Hi, you just forgot to include that timing plugin. It's only one line. See http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/#include

Comment: I had the plugin reference in there. I'm still getting the "no method repeat" error. Another issue is that the divs are all on top of each other (because of absolute positioning) but they should be relative to their parent <li>.